# Long running post request is received twice on test server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

On a long running post handled by an ASP.Net MVC application we see the behavior that after a minute or two the request is received again by the Server. That is, without doing anything client side the controller method is called again.

This is a high impact bug for us as we rely on long running post operations.

In an effort to isolate the bug I have started to remove variables from the set-up in which this bug occurs. I have managed to isolate it to a toy ASP.Net MVC project with a single controller, and static html file. The controller consists of the following code:

```
public class UploadController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Starting upload");
        while (true) Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return View();
    }
}
```

And the static html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="../Upload/Upload" method="post">
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you open a single to tab to `upload.html`, attach a debugger to the AppPool, submit the form and then leave the browser window open the following behavior is observed: Immediately after pressing the button a line `Starting upload` appears in the output window and after a few minutes (this varies from 2m30s to 5+m) a second line appears in the output window, identical to the first one.

This bug happens in both Chrome, Edge and using the API test tool Postman. Which leads me to believe it is not a browser problem.

As for environments on which it occurs: It does not happen when debugging the site with IISExpress, nor does it happen if I deploy the simple site to an IIS 10.0 instance running on my Windows 10 dev env. However, if I'm deploying to the test or staging environment on Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.5 the bug does manifest. And `Starting upload` appears twice in the output.

The fact that it doesn't happen on an IIS instance running locally makes me believe that I misconfigured something on test and staging. Is anyone familiar with settings that could have this effect? As I cannot find any information online.

Edit: I just hijacked the server of another dev team running Server 2016 and IIS 10.0 and the double request occurs on that server as well.

Comment: What does the network trace look like in the browser? What is the infinite sleep supposed to accomplish?

Comment: The browser network trace (Chrome in this case) doesn't record any of the posts that are sent. Which confuses me even more. The infinite sleep in this case is just to reproduce the bug. It accomplishes nothing but it's just there to keep the request running indefinitely. In the actual application there's code there to process the upload of GBs of data, which usually takes 10+ minutes.

Comment: Chrome will record the initial POST at the very least. I suspect you have some network hardware such as a load balancer that's timing out. My company routinely takes multi-GB files from clients, and we've had to adjust various timeouts in our load balancer to make sure the connection doesn't get closed prematurely. Be aware this can make you vulnerable to DoS attacks, so it may be better to host the file uploads on a separate domain to limit the impact as much as possible.

Comment: @mason The three servers on which this bug occurs are all hosted by an external party. Of those three servers two are definitely behind a firewall and load balancer, the third is probably behind a firewall and load balancer as well. Do you have any follow up ideas how I might verify this further? Secondly, even the initial post request is not recorded by Chrome. I have Preserve logging on and am recording and all I see is the get.

Comment: @mason I attempted the infinite post again, only this time while using Wireshark to capture traffic on the client and server. There I saw that the post is started correctly, TPC Keep alives are exchanged and eventually the client receives a FIN from the server, while the server side wireshark does not record any FIN being sent. This FIN prompts the client to resend the whole POST request. Now I'm just a graduate student and not an experienced network engineer or anything so I'm not sure if this is because of some hardware/interruption between client and server. But this points to that, right?

Comment: Yes, especially if you are doing multi-GB files. Uploading a multi-GB file over FTP is not a normal situation that network hardware is configured to handle. All sorts of timeouts in the system are designed to keep a request from remaining open that long. So it's best to avoid doing it over HTTP if you can, and instead offer an FTP interface. I realize that doesn't always line up with business objectives though. So you'll need to work with whoever manages the network hardware to adjust the settings appropriately.

Comment: I actually supported a move from FTP to HTTP as this drastically reduces the complexity of our deployment set-ups. The solution I was thinking of was implementing something like the upload of we transfer and send the file in 100MB increments until the full file is transmitted. Also, could you please post the load balancer suggestion as an answer, so that I can accept your answer.